Azure function app configured with AAD application protected by APIM fails to authenticate with redirect url
I have an Azure function app with Microsoft Identity Provider integration (AAD application) and Inbound traffic configuration with restricted Public network access enabled, set to 'Enabled from select virtual networks and IP Addresses as shown in image 1 and 2.
AAd application url: https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback 
Also, the application is protected via API Management service which blocks the function app if accessed via https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net url
The azure function app (V4 function app proxies disabled) has a swagger page, to secure swagger page itself not the endpoints (which is handled via client credentials that's working) enabled Authentication in FunctionApp.
When I try to reach the swagger ui page on url https://apimanager.com/api/swagger/ui  redirects to Microsoft login server, able to provide the username password and finally redirects to https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback which gives forbidden error.
Is there a way override the redirect url with any policy configuration to overcome the default redirection to myfunction.azurewebsites.net callback url?
 https://https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?response_type=...&redirect_uri=https://myfunctionapp.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback&client_id=...&state=redir%3D%/api/swagger/ui




Where have you configured Enabled from select virtual networks and IP Addresses in function app, I see in function app you have Enabled for all network?

I also have enabled network settings to Enabled from select virtual networks and IP Addresses in Azure Function app and added Public IP of APIM in IP Address block when adding rule in Access restrictions.
Then Added Microsoft Authentication with all the default settings in function app.
Once, you have enabled the select virtual networks and IP Addresses settings in function app then you can't access the function app URL directly. It will give you 403 error. There are multiple ways to access the function app, refer this Blog to know more about it. Here I am accessing the function app behind APIM.
In order to access the function app in APIM, I am generating a token as shown below and then adding it to the request header while invoking.




Thanks for replying Ikhtesam. I have all these settings in place and integrated with MSFT Entra application as an Identity Provider. The problem is the application redirect url is directly linked with az function custom domain (myfunction.azurewebsites.net) and the redirect url looks like https://myfunction.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/aad/callback and which I'm blocking if the request directly issued to az function. What I'm trying to look is, allow only authorized users to have access to swagger ui page (/api/swagger/ui) but apim throws forbidden after successful user authentication

Can you share the screenshots and steps of what you have configured
